# how can i add <li> to <ui> and add <ui> to the new <li> from code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

how can i add new **li** to ui and add ui to the new **li** 
i have a menu in html and i need passing value from code behind to html
example :

```
< ui> < li>from code < ui> from code < li>from code Sub menu < /li> < /ui> < /li> < /ui>
```

My html Code : read value from code behind

Menu

Sub Menu

My C# Code // two funcations

```
private void GetMenuData()
    {
        DataSet table = new DataSet();
        string strCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        string sql = @"SELECT 'p' + .... etc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(table);
        DataView view = new DataView(table.Tables[0]);
        view.RowFilter = "pID is NULL";
        foreach (DataRowView row in view)
        {
            if (!row["url"].ToString().Contains("AdminPage"))
            {
                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(row["name"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString());

                HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                tabs.Controls.Add(li);
                HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                anchor.Attributes.Add("href",row["url"].ToString());
                anchor.InnerText = row["name"].ToString();
                HtmlGenericControl ui = new HtmlGenericControl("ui");
                li.Controls.Add(anchor);
                li.Controls.Add(ui);

                AddChildItems(table.Tables[0], menuItem, ui);
            }
        }
    }
private void AddChildItems(DataTable table, MenuItem menuItem,HtmlGenericControl ui)
    {

        DataView view = new DataView(table);
        DataView viewItem = new DataView(table);
        viewItem.RowFilter = "pID=" + menuItem.Value;
        foreach (DataRowView childView in viewItem)
        {

            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            ui.Controls.Add(li);
            HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", childView["url"].ToString());
            anchor.InnerText = childView["name"].ToString();
            li.Controls.Add(anchor);
        }
    }
```